# Couldn't find User with 'id'=9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did `rails db:migrate:reset` and `rails db:migrate`,and then I accessed to `localhost:3000` found the error
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WelcomeController#index`
`Couldn't find User with 'id'=9`.
I have changed db from SQLite3 to postgre before this command in order for deploying on heroku.

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
lass ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||=User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end


  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to new_session_path, alert: 'plz sign in or sign up' if current_user.nil?
  end

  def admin_authorize
    redirect_to new_session_path,
    alert: "Only for Admin!" unless current_user.admin
  end
end
```

**error log**

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-27 15:39:23 +0900
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6
  Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (4.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=9):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `current_user'
app/views/shared/_navigation.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_shared__navigation_html_erb__2712194429362090156_70209715304560'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2819014747178102869_70209752482340'
```

Comment: log out or expire session if record is not present with flash message showing appropriate message.

Comment: Sorry, it was a lack of explanation. When I accessed , this error message appeared.

Comment: If this is for production use, consider an existing authentication gem like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below,

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||=User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

`find_by_id` is finder method which will return nil if record for an id provided through session is not present.
Further you can add filter to redirect to login page by expiring session as `session[:user_id] = nil`

I had following case in Rails API app,

```
User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
```